# Java ReentrantLock and Condition | producers finish work, consumer gets stuck

Tags: java, multithreading, conditional-statements, reentrantlock

**General Information:**
Three reader-threads read randomly from a file in chunks where each chunk has an ID and they write to a normal ArrayList. A writer-thread writes to an outputfile as soon as a chunk with the needed ID is added to the list.

For that reason I have written a BlockingChunkList which should synchronize the add() and getNextChunk() methods.

It works for me with synchronized + notify + notifyAll in one case and with a synchronized list in another.

I don't manage to do it when I use ReentrantLock and Condition. The writer-thread only writes four chunks and then he gets stuck.

**Why it might not work:**
I have the suspicion that once the readers are done the writer doesn't get the lock back. However i would expect that everytime when there is something to write (available=true) then the writer thread should be called. They seem to ignore hasAccess.await() when available is true.

**How it should work:**
The reading threads only call the add method and they release the writing thread only when there is something to write (available). They also block themselves when available=true. This lock is released when the writer has written something by calling hasAccess.signalAll()
The writing thread only calls the getNextChunk() method and he releases the other threads when he wrote the chunk. He blocks himself when available=false and he is released by the readers.

**Question:**
The reading threads finish their work and the writing thread only writes the first 4 chunks. I expect that the writer is always called when available=true.

I don't need an exact solution, a hint is appreciated as well since I think I am missing something. So: What am I missing ?

Thank You

EDIT: Concurrency is handeled only in the posted class. The main-method only starts the treads.
EDIT 2: This is one of my first shots at concurrency. I know that ArrayList is not thread safe. I would like to make it so by using ReentrantLock and Condition in order to understand the concepts. The **BASIC** idea is to block either reader or writer whether available is true or false.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

    public class BlockingChunkQueue {

        private final ArrayList<Chunk> chunks;
        private volatile int currentID = 0; // first ID for which the writer needs to wait
        private volatile boolean available; // true if the ID is in the list

        private final Lock listLock;
        private final Condition hasAccess;

        public BlockingChunkQueue(){ 
            chunks = new ArrayList<>(); 
            listLock = new ReentrantLock();
            hasAccess = listLock.newCondition();
            available = false;
        }

        /*
         * While there is a chunk which might be written to the output (=correct ID) then wait for access.
         * Then add the chunk and if the added chunk has the ID for which the other thread is waiting, then,
         * then available = true and signal the waiting thread.
         * 
         * 
         */
        public void add(Chunk chunk) throws InterruptedException{
            listLock.lock();
            try{
                while(available){
                    hasAccess.await(); // reader block yourself until you get the lock back
                }
                chunks.add(chunk);

            if(chunk.getId() == currentID){
                available = true;
                hasAccess.signalAll();
            }
            }finally{
                listLock.unlock();
            }
        }

        /*
         * If the chunk is not available then wait.
         * If it becomes available then increment the ID, remove it from the list, signal the reader-threads and set available false.
         * return the chunk which will be written to the output.
         */
        public Chunk getNextChunk() throws InterruptedException {
            listLock.lock();
            try{
                while(!available){
                    hasAccess.await(); // block yourself until u can write something
                }

                for(Chunk c : chunks){
                    if(c.getId() == currentID){
                        currentID++;
                        chunks.remove(c);
                        hasAccess.signalAll(); //signal the readers
                        available = false;
                        return c;
                    }
                }

            }finally{
                listLock.unlock();
            }
            return null;
        }

        public int getcurrentID(){ return currentID;}

        public boolean isEmpty(){ return chunks.isEmpty(); }

        public int size(){return chunks.size();}
    }
```

**SOLUTION:**
There was nothing wrong with handling the threads. It turned out to be a logical error from my side. The writing thread gets stuck because he doesn't get the chance to check for the necessary IDs because the writers read the chunks randomly. Thanks for the helpfull answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a several of problems here.

What is the purpose of the volatile variable `available` which is only read or mutated while the `lock` is held?

The `isEmtpy` and `size` methods call methods on `chunks` without holding the `lock`. `ArrayList` is not thread-safe. The behavior of these calls cannot be predicted.

A reason you might get stuck is if multiple chunks get added before getNextChunk is called.

In your loop to find the "current" you set available to false, but it may actually already be in the list:

```
            for(Chunk c : chunks){
                if(c.getId() == currentID){
                    currentID++;
                    chunks.remove(c);
                    hasAccess.signalAll(); //signal the readers
                    available = false;
                    return c;
                }
            }
```

Consider storing your chunks in a `Map<Integer,Chunk>` so that can easily see if a chunk is present by the identifier.

Comment: So should i only use volatile for global variables among threads not within classes which are used by them ? To my understanding volatile means that it's guaranteed for other threads to see the volatile values. The purpose is to show the other thread that the next chunk is ready to write. Would it be smarter to do that stuff in the main method ? This are my first shots at concurrency.

Comment: The use of locks also provide memory consistency guarantees.

Comment: but as soon as available = true the readers shouldnt be able to add anything because they get access to the while loop which contains hasAccess.await() the idea is to lock readers and writers whether available is true or false.

Comment: I understand that it would be better to use something different, but i would like to understand the concepts by using something which is not thread-safe.

Comment: That assumes that chunks are always added in order. If that is the case, this a List is not needed. Indeed a SynchronousQueue would then satisfy your use case.

Comment: The chunks are added randomly and the writer should be notified when the first chunk which should be written is available (0, 1, 2 ...)

Comment: And do you want the adding thread to block to force addition in correct order? In which case you are back to not needing a List. If you do not want to block the adding thread then the getNextChunk method must determine whether the next chunk id is already in the list or not.

Comment: The question is more about why this implementation does not work rather than, that another implementation is better. It works with two different implementations but not with this one and i don't get why, so in order to understand the issue I'd rather understand why it doesn't work than trying to find a work-around which wouldn't be difficult. But thanks for your effort. If i find an answer I'll post it.

Comment: I told you why it does not work. You have multiple entires in the list (say 2,1,0) when finally a reader thread pulls out 0. You then remove chunk 0 form the list, increment currentId to 1, set available to false. At this point available will never again be set to true, because chunk 1 is already in the list.

Comment: Now i get it. Yes this makes sense. I'll try this tomorrow and then give you of course the accepted answer if this was the case. Thank You